# How to execute a select statement multiple times in mySql?

Tags: mysql, select, benchmarking

Hi i am trying to benchmark the select performance of mySql database. I am wondering how I can execute the select statement multiple times. At the moment I have the following loop :

```
BEGIN
label1: LOOP
SET p1 = p1 - 1;
IF p1 > 0 THEN
SELECT * FROM FOOD WHERE ID = p1;
ITERATE label1;
END IF;
LEAVE label1;
END LOOP label1;
END
```

However when running this stored procedure in phpMyAdmin it returns no results.

Update

Stored procedure code

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `mySelect`(IN `p1` INT)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
label1: LOOP
SET p1 = p1 - 1;
IF p1 > 0 THEN
SELECT * FROM FOOD where id = p1;
ITERATE label1;
END IF;
LEAVE label1;
END LOOP label1;
END
```

How can I execute a select statement like this multiple times e.g. 1000 to see how long (ms) it takes to run?

Comment: where are you setting the original value of p1 to a value greater than 0?

Comment: this code is a part of a stored procedure. e.g call mySelect(100). where 100 is the number of times i want the sql select statement to run

Comment: can you share your create statement for the stored procedure?

Comment: done, updated original post

Comment: there is a benchmarking tool. just sayin'

Comment: benchmark() function is very limited. And i dont know how to use benchmarking software

Comment: Wait, sorry...  you're trying specifically to benchmark.  Try mysqlslap, whis is already in your mysql/bin directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with strawberry... I used mysqlslap

```
>mysqlslap --concurrency=50 --iterations=5 --query=test1.sql --create-schema=test -uroot -p
Benchmark
        Average number of seconds to run all queries: 0.031 seconds
        Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.031 seconds
        Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.031 seconds
        Number of clients running queries: 50
        Average number of queries per client: 1
```

Inside test1.sql I wrote:

```
SELECT * FROM food WHERE id=(1+ FLOOR(RAND() * 10))
```